# Can't extract data from Redux Toolkit 2.0 in my NextJS 14 app

Tags: mongodb, next.js, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am creating a NextJs 14 ecommerce application using redux toolkit for state management. I have created a slice using my best understanding of RTK 2.0 syntax to call user data  so that it can be added to my user state.

```js
"use client";

import { buildCreateSlice, asyncThunkCreator } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const createSliceWithThunks = buildCreateSlice({
  creators: {
    asyncThunk: asyncThunkCreator,
  },
});

const initialState = {
  user: {
    _id: "",
    fname: "",
    lname: "",
    email: "",
    streetAddress: "",
    postalCode: "",
    city: "",
    county: "",
    country: "",
  },
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

const userSlice = createSliceWithThunks({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: (create) => ({
    fetchUser: create.asyncThunk(
      async (_, thunkApi) => {
        const response = await fetch("/api/user");
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch user data");
        }
        const userData = await response.json();
        console.log(userData);
        return userData;
      },
      {
        pending: (state) => {
          (state.loading = true), (state.error = null);
        },
        fulfilled: (state, action) => {
          state.loading = false;
          state.data = action.payload;
        },
        rejected: (state, action) => {
          state.loading = false;
          state.error = action.error.message;
        },
      }
    ),
  }),
});

export const { fetchUser } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

This is my api/user route:

```js
import { connectDb } from "@dbConfig/db";
import User from "@models/UserModel";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req, res) {
  const session = getServerSession(); //using my session data from NextAuth to get email to find user in mongodb

  try {
    const email = (await session).user.email; //I don't know why prettier formatted this line like this, the code breaks if I change it.

    connectDb();

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    console.log(user);

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "User found:", user }, { status: 201 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

The call works perfectly, I am getting the user data from my database and can see it when I go to localhost:3000/api/user.
The problem is when I try to get it using Redux-Toolkit and then set my user state to the data received.
When I check the Redux-Devtools in my browser, I can see the data, but it is only appearing under a `data` property, and not actually updating state. I am at a loss for how to move forward. Any help is appreciated.

[image: redux dev tool screenshot]

Comment: Someone suggested an edit, but they unfortunately modified the code in the process which would be incorrect for Next.js. I've corrected the edit. You *should* be able to see, and approve, suggested edits on your own posts though IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state ***is*** actually updating, you can see the updated state in the dev tool.

***However...***

There is no `data` property in the state until this `fetchUser` action is fulfilled, in which case the reducer case sets a `state.data` property equal to `action.payload`. I suspect you want to be setting the `state.user` property to the `user` property of the response JSON in the action payload, e.g. `state.user = action.payload.user;`.

```js
const initialState = {
  user: {
    _id: "",
    fname: "",
    lname: "",
    email: "",
    streetAddress: "",
    postalCode: "",
    city: "",
    county: "",
    country: "",
  },
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};
```

```js
const userSlice = createSliceWithThunks({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: (create) => ({
    fetchUser: create.asyncThunk(
      async (_, thunkApi) => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch("/api/user");
          const userData = await response.json();
          return userData;
        } catch(error) {
          return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
        }
      },
      {
        pending: (state) => {
          state.loading = true;
          state.error = null;
        },
        fulfilled: (state, action) => {
          state.loading = false;
          state.user = action.payload.user; // <-- update user property
        },
        rejected: (state, action) => {
          state.loading = false;
          state.error = action.payload.message;
        },
      }
    ),
  }),
});
```